# Mostrar data e hora ao utilizador atual

Tags: php

Tenho este código:

```
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {

$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="date" name= "Data[]" id= "Data" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?> <input type="time" required="" id="Hora" name="Hora[]" value="<?php echo date("H:i:s");?></td>';
}
```

Mas nem mostra a data atual nem a hora atual como mostro na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema está nas aspas: `value="<?php echo date("H:i:s");?>` coloque assim `value="<?php echo date(\"H:i:s\");?>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve concatenar:

```
$tabela1 .= '<td> <input type="date" name= "Data[]" id= "Data" value="'. date("Y-m-d") .'"> <input type="time" required="" id="Hora" name="Hora[]" value="' . date("H:i:s") . '"></td>';
```

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado